# unable to run apt-get ugrade

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I receive the following error when attempting to run 'sudo apt-get upgrade'

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tzdata-java : Depends: tzdata (= 2015c-0ubuntu0.12.04) but 2015f-0ubuntu0.12.04 is installed

Answer (score 0):

Try removing that package

`sudo apt-get remove --purge tzdata`

and run

`sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y`

If that does not work

```
sudo dpkg --remove tzdata
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: I get the following..

steve@rc-dev2:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge tzdata
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: tzdata but it is not going to be installed
 libc6 : Depends: tzdata but it is not going to be installed
 libical0 : Depends: tzdata but it is not going to be installed
 php5-cli : Depends: tzdata but it is not going to be installed
 tzdata-java : Depends: tzdata (= 2015c-0ubuntu0.12.04) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-minimal : Depends: tzdata but it is not going to be installed
 util-linux : Depends: tzdata (>= 2006c-2) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: running sudo apt-get install -f results in:

Various errors including...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-6-jre-lib:
 openjdk-6-jre-lib depends on openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b27); however:
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless is not configured yet.
  Errors were encountered while processing:
 tzdata-java
 openjdk-6-jre-headless
 icedtea-6-jre-cacao
 icedtea-6-jre-jamvm
 openjdk-6-jre-lib
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
steve@rc-dev2:~$

Comment: Is this box an ec2 instance any chance ?

Comment: if I try and remove openjdk-6-jre-headless it complains other packages depend on it, including openjdk-6-jre-lib. If I try and remove that package it complains that tzdata depends on it.  seems like circular dependancies